# How to include custom jQuery / javascript in magento 1.8

Tags: javascript, php, magento

I have a custom javascript and jQuery code.

I am new to magento and need to know how to add those jquery and JS snippet into my magento so that it identifies those.

Im trying to show tooltip on page load and hide after sometime using the below **JS fiddle link**:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvzuz/17/

The fiddle uses the following files:

1) jquery
2) bootstrap.js
3) bootstrap.css

Accordingly i have updated my magento files as:

In **app\design\frontend\rau\default\template\page\html\pager.phtml**

```
<?php if($followupbuttonshow){?>
    <div class="thiscategory">
        <a class="followlink" href="javascript:void" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="Place your stuff here"> <?php echo $this->__('Follow'); ?></a>  
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

**UPDATED:**

In **app\design\frontend\rau\default\layout\local.xml**

```
<reference name="head">
      <action method="addJs"><js>jquery/jquery.js</js></action>
      <action method="addJs"><js>jquery/jquery.noconflict.js</js></action>
      <action method="addLinkRel"><rel>text/javascript</rel><href>https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/js/bootstrap.js</href></action>
      <action method="addLinkRel"><rel>text/css</rel><href>https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/css/bootstrap.css</href></action>
   </reference>
...
```

in **app\design\frontend\rau\default\layout\page.xml**

```
<default translate="label" module="page">
   <action method="addJs"><script>js/custom.js</script></action>
```

In **rauqa\skin\frontend\rau\default\js\custom.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('tooltipp js....');
    $j('.thiscategory .followlink').tooltip().eq(0).tooltip('show').tooltip('disable').one('mouseout', function() {
    $j(this).tooltip('enable');
    });

setTimeout(function() {
$j('.thiscategory .followlink').tooltip().eq(0).tooltip('hide').tooltip('enable');
}, 5000);

});
```

**Error in console:**

> tooltipp js....
>
> tooltip.js?q=29032018:3 Uncaught TypeError: $j(...).tooltip is not a function
>
> at HTMLDocument. (tooltip.js?q=29032018:3)
>
> at j (jquery.min.js?q=29032018:2)
>
> at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js?q=29032018:2)
>
> at Function.ready (jquery.min.js?q=29032018:2)
>
> at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.min.js?q=29032018:2)

**To Verify if the js are loaded below is the screenshot:**

custom.js file loaded

[image]

jquery loaded- not sure if this is the actual jquery file

This is the only jquery loaded
[image]

**cdn for bootstrap.js and css loaded**

[image]

Link to jquery :

[image]

**Problem:**

Not sure if i have included all the files correctly in the correct manner (html, xml)

Please point out where the issue is.. And the way i have to include the scripts for magento to identify.

Comment: ... and what exactly is the problem? Apart from the fact that Magento uses Prototype rather than jQuery (depending on version).

Answer (score 1):

You will just need to put the pasted `script` into the phtml file and it should work. If jquery is not linked to the page, then link it. Also, pay attention to the naming of the jquery variable. In many cases its name is `$`, but you use it as `jQuery` in your `script`.

Comment: Have updated the question @Lajos, have removed the 'jQuery' and just used $..i get the error Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ready is not a function

Comment: You often use `jQuery` in Magneto as Prototype also uses `$` ... Magento's compatibility kit assigns `$j` to jQuery IIRC.

Comment: @stack200s please show how did you link jquery into your page.

Comment: @stack200s I cannot see in your question the exact way you have loaded jquery. You will need something like <script type="text/javascript" src="yourpathtojquery"></script> and I think this is missing from your code.

Comment: @stack200s you will need to either have a copy of jquery, possibly in the folder of rauqa/skin/frontend/rau/default/js, or link it from an online source, like https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js. Either way, you will need to have a script tag like your script tags shown in the image of your question.

Comment: @stack200s do you have a script tag in your generated HTML where the source contains jquery.js?

Comment: @stack200s that must be the problem. You will need to include all the Javascript you use into script tags, as the browser will not know by itself what Javascript files are to be used and where to load them from. But before you do this, check the generated HTML in your browser, using right-click and view source to see whether the scripts are somehow loaded.

Comment: @stack200s if you search for jquery.js in the view source, what do you find?

Comment: Hi @LajosArpad, i just tried to replicate the same code in my newly created fiddle, in the fiddle too i get toolbar.js is not a function...https://jsfiddle.net/uqxu32op/   how do i find what are the files required from the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/apougher/Lvzuz/

Comment: @stack200s since you have checked that jquery and tooltip are both loaded into the browser, if your problem still persists, you might be loading jquery from the wrong location, or you might be loading jquery before tooltip. Since jquery is a dependency of tooltip, if tooltip is loaded before jquery, then jquery was not yet loaded when tooltip needed it. If your problem still persists, then your might need to edit your question and add the way you have included the Javascript files into the page.

Comment: Hi @LajosArpad, i have updated the complete question...request you to suggest on this pls

Comment: @stack200s You try to load jquery from jquery/jquery.js, while the actual file is at default/js/jquery.js. This seems to be a problem.

Comment: Ok i somehow was able to do it by loading the bootstrap css,js, jquery-noconflict.js all from my local path ..It was the issue with multiple versions and jquery no conflict alias names...thanks for the help @LajosArpad and everyone out there

Comment: @stack200s you are welcome. If there was a correct answer, then please, accept it as such, so future visitors will be able to see that the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your JavaScript file is missing closing: 
`);`

Edit for new error: $ is Prototype in Magento, but you're using jQuery in the code. If you have jQuery added, use the alias that was assigned to it (such as $j). Or:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('tooltipp....');
    jQuery('.thiscategory .followlink').tooltip().eq(0).tooltip('show').tooltip('disable').one('mouseout', function() {
        jQuery(this).tooltip('enable');
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('.thiscategory .followlink').tooltip().eq(0).tooltip('hide').tooltip('enable');
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Please check my updated question, even after replacing the jQuery with alias like $j, i still get the same error

Comment: If you view the code of the page as it renders in browser, is tooltip.js present? And if so, does it actually load (not 404)?

Comment: Which tooltip.js library is this? If it's the Bootstrap one, you'll also need Bootstrap JS.

Comment: That example uses Bootstrap, and its Tooltip. There's no tooltip.js, just jQuery and Bootstrap. View frame source on the jsfiddle shows it. view-source:fiddle.jshell.net/apougher/Lvzuz/show/

Comment: In the last fiddle, JS and CSS were added with "http://" which results in them not being loaded, as fiddle uses "https://".

Comment: ya i updated the fiddle link with https...oh yes..correct...if i add https for bootstrap cdn links..they seem to work...can u please tell where to add the same 2 links in my magento pages...i guess im almost close

Comment: For the sake of a test, add jquery and bootstrap in your head.phtml, check if it works then. If it does, then update XML to make it proper.

Comment: Hi @djdy, hve updated my complete question..could you please suggest on this now